# The most elegant way to collect nonEmpty object fields from the list of objects

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of objects, for example

```
case class MyClass(paramA: Option[String], paramB: String)

val myList = List[MyClass]
```

I need to make a new List[String] which contains nonEmpty paramA values from myList. For example,

```
val myList = List(MyClass(None,"abc"),
                  MyClass("AAA","xyz"), 
                  MyClass("BBB","xyz"))

//the result must be List("AAA","BBB")
```

What is the most elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of `myList` as given don't conform to the type `MyClass` since `paramA` is expected to be an `Option[String]`. So, add `Some(...)` to the first parameter of the last two elements like so:

```
scala> val myList = List(MyClass(None,"abc"),
     |                   MyClass(Some("AAA"),"xyz"), 
     |                   MyClass(Some("BBB"),"xyz"))
```

Then, we can use `flatMap` over `paramA` which returns the value in the Option if it is `Some`

```
scala> myList.flatMap(_.paramA)
res3: List[String] = List(AAA, BBB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to [@Brian's `flatMap` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49986495/9297144) which makes use of `collect`:

```
myList.collect{ case MyClass(Some(paramA), _) => paramA }
```

[`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):List[B]) filters elements for which a `case` is defined and for these elements, it applies a `map` transformation.